# Как найти три самые частоповторяющиеся элементы из строки (списка)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Имеется строка из файла, и нужно найти 3 самые частоповторяющиеся элементы в этой строке. Вначале я думал сделать из строки список и применить метод sort() или sorted() и в значение key= поставить функцию лямбду, использующую count(), но не получилось. Теперь я решил сделать по другому и использовать цикл for для строки, но тоже что то не получается. Если знаете, то скажите, как список с помощью лямбды отсортировать, чтобы найти 3 самых частоповторяющихся элемента и еще как код который внизу написан исправить.

```
def fdx_1 ():
    with open('tecst.txt') as o:
        nom = []
        pe = o.read()

        for i in range(len(pe)):
            try:
                if pe.count(pe[i]) > pe.count(pe[i + 1]):
                    nom.append(pe[i])

            except IndexError:
                break

    return nom
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы найти три самых частовстречающихся символа (Unicode codepoint) в файле, [можно `collections.Counter` использовать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from collections import Counter
from operator import itemgetter

with open('input.txt') as file:
    counter = Counter(char for line in file for char in line)

print(*map(itemgetter(0), counter.most_common(3))) # winners
```

Answer (score 2):

Составляешь хистограмму- карту (dict) где  ключом будут элементы списка а значением их количество